# android viewpager adapter and NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

Sometimes I'm getting NullPointerExceptions in google play reports, where (as I think) I use viewpager or it's adapter. This is my code:

```
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mPagerView;

private static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    HashMap<Integer, PageFragment> mPageReferenceMap;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, PageFragment>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        PageFragment fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(position);
        mPageReferenceMap.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
    }

    public PageFragment getFragment(int key) {
        return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

in onCreate():

```
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagerView = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Then, at this line I'm getting crash reports from some users:

```
 mPagerAdapter.getFragment(mPagerView.getCurrentItem()).whatEverFunctionFromFragment();
```

I call fragments this way in different places (independent of each other) - in onDismiss function of the dialog, in onItemClick of ListPopupWindow, etc - with different functions in fragment.

**More info:** I've got this error after I have done everything that sad [Heinrisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897294/android-viewpager-adapter-and-nullpointerexception#comment19255183_13897294). This error appears when user resumes to the activity. But I still don't understand how to fix it and why is it happening? Should I save `mPageReferenceMap` in onSaveInstanceState()? or in onStop()? What am I missing in lifecycle of Activity and Fragments?

Comment: You should provide more details, like from where(and when) do you call that line. Also, it there a specific Android version on which this happens?

Comment: Fragments are added since API 11. Do you target the correct API in the market?

Comment: Luksprog: I will add more details today.
Mohamed: as you can see I'm using SupportFragmentManager.

Comment: I added some more explanation and some more code.

Comment: As a note you might consider using HockeyApp or something similar so that you get the full stack trace from crashes in your app. Has helped me immensely

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with Activity resuming. Test to go into developer settings and check "Don't keep activities" and "No background processes". In the app, press the home button and then resume the app and see if everything is working.

Comment: Heinrisch: Wow, after that I got this errors. I'll edit my answer now, but I still don't understand how to fix this problem?

Comment: Still no stack trace or at least a tip which line is called when the NPE appears...

Comment: what do you mean? NPE is usual. The tip which line is called exists from the beginning: "Then, at this line I'm getting crash reports from some users:". Actually it is not one. NPE appear every time when I call mPagerAdapter.getFragment() after activity stops and restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is storing `mPageReferenceMap` when app stops and restarts. The best way I've found for storing fragment references is [putFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#putFragment%28android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.Fragment%29) and [getFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragment%28android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String%29) methods of FragmentManager.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for(int i=0;i<mPagerAdapter.getCount();i++)
        fm.putFragment(savedInstanceState,"fragment"+Integer.toString(i),mPagerAdapter.getFragment(i));
}
```

and in onCreate() method (when Activity restarts):

```
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int i=0;i<mPagerAdapter.getCount();i++){
            PageFragment pf = (PageFragment)fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState,"fragment"+Integer.toString(i));
            if(pf!=null)
                mPagerAdapter.putFragment(i,pf);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should post the stacktrace that you are getting when reproducing this error.

Just guessing but might it be the mPageReferenceMap that returns null when resuming. The reason for this would be that the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is holding on to the fragments and is only calling getItem when it needs a new fragment. However, the FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not hold on to the information in mPageReferenceMap. So if the adapter restores the fragments without calling getItem, your fragments will be there but there will not be a reference in mPageReferenceMap.